# Check if Locked Pages In Memory is enabled

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

On SQL Server 2014, is there a way to check and see if Locked Pages in Memory is enabled for a list of target servers? I need to come up with a list of all servers that have this enabled on them in order to create an alert.

Comment: [Maybe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/developers-choice-programmatically-identify-lpim-and-ifi-privileges-in-sql-server/). `sys.dm_os_memory_info` has been extended on recent versions of SQL Server, but oddly enough, while SQL Server 2012 is mentioned as having been retrofitted with this column, SQL Server 2014 is not, either in this post or the documentation. So you might actually strike out. If your systems are 64-bit, a possible alternative is checking `awe_allocated_kb` in `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks`, as this is the amount of locked memory allocated.

Comment: I don't have a 2014 instance handy, so just commenting in case it doesn't work.  But you can query the server log.  SQL Server logs whether or not it's using lock pages in memory during startup.  `EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'locked pages';`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the information! It looks like I should be able to use sys.dm_os_sys_info.sql_memory_model to check for values greater than one, in that case it is enabled for the service account. I should be able to go from there. Thanks!

Comment: @squillman: a problem with this is that it can give false negatives if the error log is cycled (automatically or manually), so you probably want to add some check to ensure you actually have the startup lines.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah, that is a very good point.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out the dbatools / dbacheck powershell modules? They are built the entire SQL Server community and they have checks for this.

```
Install-Module dbatools

Get-DbaPrivilege -Computername ZYX
```

That should list you Bactch Logon Privileges, Instant File Initialization Privileges and Lock Pages in Memory Privileges.